# Assigning values to array vba

Tags: vba, excel

I don't have experience using arrays in VBA and I got lost. What I try to do is the following:

In the column A I have ~15 strings (number is not fixed sometimes it is more sometimes less)

I remove duplicates and then for each name in the column A I would like to create separate sheet in the file.

I created an array to which I tried to assign each name from A with this loop:

```
Sub assigningvalues()

Dim i As Integer
Dim myArray(20) As Variant
Dim finalrow As Long

ActiveSheet.Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1)

finalrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlDown).Row

'For i = 2 To finalrow -> I get overflow error when I use this range   
For i = 2 To Cells(20, 1)  
    myArray(i) = Cells(i, 1).Value    
Next i

'I check with the lines below if values were assigned    
Cells(2, 4).Value = myArray(4)
Cells(3, 4).Value = myArray(2)

End Sub
```

Nevertheless values from the cells to do not assign to the array

Moreover when I try to use `finalrow` as range for the loop I get overflow error (It is not a big problem as there are workarounds, although it would be nice to know what I've done wrong)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the code below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub assigningvalues()

Dim i As Long
Dim myArray(20) As Variant
Dim FinalRow As Long
Dim Sht As Worksheet

Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' modify "Sheet1" to your sheet's name

With Sht
    .Range("A1", .Range("A1").End(xlDown)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1)

    FinalRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' get last row in column "A"

    For i = 2 To FinalRow
        myArray(i) = Cells(i, 1).Value
    Next i

    'I check with the lines below if values were assigned
    .Cells(2, 4).Value = myArray(4)
    .Cells(3, 4).Value = myArray(2)
End With

End Sub
```

**Note**: you can read the contents of the `Range` to a 1-D Array without a `For` loop, using `Application.Transpose`, you need to change the line you define it to:

```
Dim myArray As Variant
```

and populate the entire array using:

```
myArray = Application.Transpose(.Range("A2:A" & FinalRow))
```

Comment: Nice tutorial content *(+1)*

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the tip.I will use it in the future

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below:

```
    Sub assigningvalues()

    Dim myArray As Variant
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1)

    myArray = ActiveSheet.Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown))


    For Each element In myArray
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)).Name = element
    Next element

End Sub
```

NOTES: The problem with your above code was, that

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlDown).Row
```

returned the absolut number of rows in the sheet, not the used ones. Since your array has length 20 and the sheet about 1 Mio. rows, you have an overflow. you can check this by using

```
Debug.Print ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlDown).Row
```

In the above code, after you remove dublicates, you again go down from `A1` to the end and save the range to an array. The array `myArray` now contains all the cell values in your reduced range.

Now you loop over the elements with

```
For Each element in myArray
```

and create a new sheet with `Workbook.Sheets.Add` and assign the name my setting `Sheets(index).name = element`

The above code should work for you. Few remarks:

Instead of using `"ActiveSheet", ThisWorkbook, etc.` You should always start a Sub with this:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook 'for the workbook containing the code
Set wb = Workbooks(workbookName) 'to reference an other Workbook

'And for all the sheets you are using
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = wb.Sheets(sheetName) 'this way you avoid problems with multiple 
                               workbooks that are open and active or 
                               unactive sheets.
```

Comment: Thank you FloLie. I will keep in mind your suggestions :)